# Passing information through open graph

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to post a verb to the timeline. Each time a user clicks the button to post to the timeline i want different information to be passed through eg
User clicks post on page one post using code

```
FB.api(
        '/me/devthree:Visited?product=http://dev3.vendorshop.net/vendor/og/testOgWebsite.aspx?Data=Product1', 'post',
```

but then on the second page when they click i want to post using code

```
FB.api(
        '/me/devthree:Visited?product=http://dev3.vendorshop.net/vendor/og/testOgWebsite.aspx?Data=Product1', 'post',
```

The post is successful but on the page testOgWebsite.aspx there is no information being passes through in the query string.  Am I going the right way about it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you intended it, but those two lines are the same.

This is how I've passed parameters:

```
FB.api('/me/devthree:Visited', 'post', {
        product: "http://dev3.vendorshop.net/vendor/og/testOgWebsite.aspx", 
        Data: "Product1"
    }, 
    function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

Note, another reason that it's probably not working is that you have two '?' in your URL as in this:

```
?Data=Product1'
```

Should be this:

```
&Data=Product1'
```